# Getting error importing facebookads content in Python

Tags: python, facebook-ads-api

I Tried using Python SDK for initializing the Marketing API thereby Importing ad objects with simple API test calls.

Getting Module Import Errors::
eg:
AS per facebook offical SDK for Python getting module name as facebookads.objects

Getting Module error:

```
from facebookads.objects import AdUser
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facebookads.objects

```
#Add to header of your file
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects

my_app_id = '{your-app-id}'
my_app_secret = '{your-app-secret}'
my_access_token = '{your-access-token}' // Your user access token
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
```

But while checking for the package name in installed facebookad packages we are getting module name as adobjects.

/Desktop/facebook_api/facebookads/adobjects# pwd
/Desktop/facebook_api/facebookads/adobjects

There are many more such errors arising while importing modules. IS there some way around to overcome these modules related errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`facebookads` 2.11.4 has no objects module or subpackage.

It does have a `facebook.adobjects.user` module that I suppose is what you are looking for.

Try using Python built-in `help()` to inspect a package or module content.

Comment: How can i get Ad_Set_ID for particular campaign so as to retrieve ad set parameters for campaign.